# Change the colour of a cell based on another cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a pixel art activity where a specific number in a cell will turn a different cell a colour if the correct answer/ number is input. 
For example if cell C2 has the correct answer of 7 then cells E1,F2, and G3 would turn Red. 
Then if cell 2 has the correct answer of 22 cells F1,G2, and E3 would turn blue. But any other number would not change the colour of those cells.

Answer (score 1):

try like this with custom formula:

```
=$C$2=7
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.

For example in cell C2 apply this rule
Format cells if: 'Custom Formula is' (dropdown)

`= E1 = 7`

now C2 should get formatting when E1 equals 7.

Note that for strings you will need to use double quotes, like this:

`= G2 = "k"`

Finally, if multiple cells need the same rule, you can click the squares icon in the 'Apply to range' input field, and then you can hold 'control' and click multiple fields.